# Import of custom class: several errors (e.g. java: not a statement)

Tags: java, import

I wrote a class which knows how to calculate the vector product and I want to call it in my main class. But when trying to use the class i get several Errors, that I can't explain or solve (see screenshot).
[Problem_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K385X.png)

[image]

Comment: try is a reserved keyword. Don't use it

Comment: Don't post code and errors as links to images. Post them as text, in the question. And please respect the Java naming conventions. Classes start with an uppercase letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`try` is keyword, you should not use it to name the variable/object.

```
xProduct productObj = new xProduct();
```

Answer (score 0):

You just can not do this:

```
xProduct try = new xProduct();
```

because try is a reserved [keyword](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html) in java